# Uso de sockets para hacer peticiones de datos

Tags: java, rest, socket.io, jersey

Tengo un lio mental en este tema debido a que no se de patrones o *best practices* que cumplan este cometido (por favor, iluminenme respecto a este tema).

Mi contexto es el siguiente, utilizando Sockets (concretamente `java.net.Socket` y `java.net.SocketServer`) tengo un cliente que realiza peticiones a un servidor. Estas peticiones pueden ser de diferentes tipos (imaginen una hipotética clase llamada `peticion` de la que heredan diferentes subclases) , por lo que el servidor posee diferentes métodos declarados para recopilar la información, en función del tipo de la petición. Esta información es tratada mediante la implementación de REST, Jersey, el propósito de las peticiones únicamente es provocar la ejecución de métodos en el servidor para actualizar la información del servidor REST.

**Mi problema es que** no se como diferenciar los tipos de peticiones que llegan al servidor y, según este, ejecutar un método u otro para actualizar la información.

**Las custiones son las siguientes**: ¿es un mal diseño si en la clase peticion establezco una variable `String` llamada `tipoPeticion` que me ayude a procesar dichas peticiones? Si no, ¿cuál es la forma correcta?¿Viene esto definido en algún patrón?¿Me equivoco y lo estoy planteando mal?

Pueden responder a cualquiera de las preguntas, pero la que más me interesaría es la segunda.

*Estoy encantado de editar el hilo si os parece que esta mál formulado!*

Comment: La  primera cuestión es porqué utilizas sockets para comunicaciones HTTP/REST. Los sockets funcionan al nivel más bajo; si trabajas directamente con socket tendrás que implementar toda la lógica HTTP (cabeceras, codificación de datos, etc.), tal y como comentas en tu pregunta. Si no hay ningún motivo que lo justifique, lo normal es que busques librerías de cliente y servidor para REST y uses éstas.

Comment: Probablemente me haya explicado mal. Uso REST como paso intermedio. Cliente hace una petición al servidor. Servidor, en funcion de la peticion, almacena la informacion extraida de otras fuentes en el servidor REST. Cliente consulta el seevidor y obtiene la informacion recientemente almacenada

Comment: Creando una variable para guardar el tipo de petición es una buena opción. Después añades el contenido de esta variable a la petición que realizas a tu servidor con el resto de los datos, y ya es programar en el servidor para que discrimine el tipo de petición y según la que reciba lo procese de una manera o de otra.

Comment: Dado que tienes que realizar diferentes acciones según la petición, creo que lo mejor sería usar un [patrón de comandos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)), esta [presentación](http://arantxa.ii.uam.es/~eguerra/docencia/0708/09%20Command.pdf) te puede servir.